# make new view of buttons from arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist of objects in my android app. I want to use this arraylist to create a new view with a button for each object in the arraylist. Each button's text would be set based on an instance variable in the object it represents. the new view should be able to react to button presses as well. What would be the best way to implement this? thank you for your time.

Comment: are you want to declare button in your layout based on Arraylist ?

Comment: I want a new view, which basically just has a button for each object in the arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code will help you to append new View to your layout  try this code clarify the idea for you and feel free to feed me back in any not obvious thing

the layout code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/yourlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

and in your `OnCreate` method add this code

```
LinearLayout yourlayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);

for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {

                    Button btn = new Button (ActivityName.this);
                    btn.setWidth(40);
                    btn.setHeight(20);
                    btn.setText(arrylist.get(i).gettext());
                    yourlayout.addView(btn);
                }
```

Comment: I don't know what i'm supposed to put for ActivityContext or yourlayout.

Comment: @user3314863 yourlayout is the references for your layout in xml file , and  ActivityContext  is your Activity context , see edited answer

Comment: LinearLayout yourlayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
is causing a nullpointer exception.

Comment: that's meaning you don't have LinearLayout in your layout xml , could you post your code ??

Comment: LinearLayout yourlayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chooseExistingLayout);

  for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) {

            Button btn = new Button (this);
            btn.setWidth(40);
            btn.setHeight(20);
            btn.setText(games.get(i).getString("Opponent"));
            yourlayout.addView(btn);
        }
  setContentView(yourlayout);

Comment: then my xml file looks like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/chooseExistingLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

</LinearLayout>

Comment: your problem in this code :
setContentView(yourlayout); 
it must be like that
setContentView(R.layout.yourxml); and put it before the findViewById method

Comment: thank you very much!, one last question, how can i make the layout scrollable if i have a bunch of buttons?

Comment: you will use ScrollView in your layout , your xml will be like that 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chooseExistingLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>